# Trying to build a Hierarchy and find the root and total count of children under a root in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

**Problem Statement:**

1. Trying to create a hierarchy in Oracle (query1)
2. Need to find the Root and total children count under each root (query2)
3. Have to build a report in PowerBI with the data output (for 1 & 2)

**Query1: to build the hierarchy**

```
SELECT 

PARENT AS "PARENT"
,CHILD AS "CHILD"
,LEVEL AS "LEVEL"
,PARENT_CLASS AS "PARENT_CLASS"
,CHILD_CLASS AS "CHILD_CLASS"
,CREATED_ON_RELCI AS "CREATED_ON_RELCI"
,UPDATED_ON_RELCI AS "UPDATED_ON_RELCI"

FROM
(   

    SELECT DISTINCT
   CI1.NAME AS PARENT
    ,CI2.NAME AS CHILD
     ,CI1.SYS_CLASS_NAME AS PARENT_CLASS
     , CI2.SYS_CLASS_NAME AS CHILD_CLASS  
     ,RELCI.SYS_CREATED_ON AS CREATED_ON_RELCI
    ,RELCI.SYS_UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED_ON_RELCI

    FROM  SN_REPORTING.REP_CMDB_REL_CI RELCI  
    LEFT JOIN SN_REPORTING.REP_CMDB_CI_SERVICE CIS
    ON RELCI.PARENT=CIS.SYS_ID
    LEFT JOIN SN_REPORTING.REP_CMDB_CI CI1
    ON RELCI.PARENT=CI1.SYS_ID
    LEFT JOIN SN_REPORTING.REP_CMDB_CI CI2
    ON RELCI.CHILD=CI2.SYS_ID

WHERE RELCI.SYS_UPDATED_ON >= TO_DATE('01-01-18', 'MM-DD-YYYY')


)A

CONNECT BY NOCYCLE A.PARENT = PRIOR A.CHILD)
```

**Query2: to find the Root and total children count under each root**

```
select ( count(*)-1 ) Child_Node_Count
,      root
from ( select connect_by_root(parent) root
       from  SN_REPORTING.SERVICE_LIFECYCLE_WITHOUT_HIERARCHY_FILTER_VW
       connect by nocycle parent = prior child
     )
     
group
by     root
/
```

**Issue Description:**

1. If I run query1 I get the hierarchy in Oracle, where in if I create a procedure with the same query its throwing error for the "HIERARCHY" column.
2. I created a procedure excluding "HIERARCHY" column in Oracle & used the same to find the Root and count of children, but query keeps on running and after some time its throwing tablespace error.
3. Also while importing data into POWERBI the data keeps on loading , and its never ends. Not able to check the total data count in DB as it shows tablespace error.

As I am new to Oracle require help to resolve the above issues, also combining query1 and query2 to receive the entire problem statement.

Sample output attached for your reference. [query1 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzvye.jpg)

Comment: You are left joining table REP_CMDB_CI_SERVICE and it is not used in further joins nor in select list, so it is needed here? And what is the error with column "HIERARCHY"?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with scalar select to dive into the hierarchy for each row, eg

```
SQL> select empno
  2       , lpad(' ', (level-1)*2) || ename as ename
  3       , ( select count(*)
  4           from emp sub
  5           start with sub.mgr = emp.empno
  6           connect by sub.mgr = prior sub.empno
  7         ) reports
  8    from emp
  9   start with mgr is null
 10   connect by mgr = prior empno
 11   order siblings by empno;

     EMPNO ENAME                   REPORTS
---------- -------------------- ----------
      7839 KING                         13
      7566   JONES                       4
      7788     SCOTT                     1
      7876       ADAMS                   0
      7902     FORD                      1
    ...
```

but of course, that can mean an expensive query for every single row.  An alternative would be pattern matching (assuming you are on 12c or above)

```
SQL> with raw_data as (
  2     select lvl, empno, ename, rownum as rn
  3     from ( select level as lvl, empno, ename
  4            from emp
  5            start with mgr is null
  6            connect by mgr = prior empno
  7            order siblings by empno  )
  8      )
  9  select empno
 10       , lpad(' ', (lvl-1)*2) || ename as ename
 11       , reports
 12  from raw_data
 13  match_recognize (
 14     order by rn
 15     measures
 16        starting_level.rn as rn
 17      , starting_level.lvl as lvl
 18      , starting_level.empno as empno
 19      , starting_level.ename as ename
 20      , count(higher_level.lvl) as reports
 21     one row per match
 22     after match skip to next row
 23     pattern (starting_level higher_level*)
 24     define  higher_level as lvl > starting_level.lvl
 25  )
 26  order by rn;

     EMPNO ENAME                   REPORTS
---------- -------------------- ----------
      7839 KING                         13
      7566   JONES                       4
      7788     SCOTT                     1
      7876       ADAMS                   0
      7902     FORD                      1
      7369       SMITH                   0
      7698   BLAKE                       5
      7499     ALLEN                     0
      ...
```

Comment: 1) Thanks for Responding. I tried the Option 1 (d do it with scalar select to dive into the hierarchy for each row) - as you mentioned expensive query for every single row. At the end its throwing tablespace error.

Comment: 2) Pattern Matching am not able to use as I don't have any level column in my query. Level column I get when I use CONNECT BY clause, which is affecting the query performance. Request you to help me remodifying the query. I am attaching my query excluding CONNECT BY clause.

Comment: LEVEL is not a pattern matching facility, it is a CONNECT BY facility

Comment: Thanks for Responding Connor. I tried pattern matching query getting the below error : ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block
01788. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY clause required in this query block"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 9

Comment: You can't start with a level, because a level is assigned as the rows are retrieved. You need a starting *condition*. And double check your lpad :-)